# Object variable or With block variable not set while sending attachment in email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I need to send attachment with email. I used following code which gives below exceptions.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable
>   not set. at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container..ctor(Object
>   Instance) at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) at
>   dynamicPage.makeCustom_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

```
try {
    generateRequestID();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    mail.To.Add("email.text");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(personEmail.Text);
    mail.Subject = "IDFC Bank BrandStore Product Customization Request";
    mail.Body = "Request ID : " + Session["requestID"].ToString + "<br>Name : " + personName.Text + "<br>Contact : " + personContact.Text + "<br>Email : " + personEmail.Text + "<br>Department : " + Department.Text + "<br>Quantity : " + quantity.Text + "<br>Description : " + customDescription.Text + "<br>Timeline : " + customTimeline.Text + "<br>Product Link : " + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "";
    if (artworkContainer.HasFile) {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(artworkContainer.PostedFile.FileName);
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(artworkContainer.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
    }
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("you@yourdomain.com", "mypassword");
    SmtpServer.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    Response.Redirect("/customization-request-sent");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.Write(ex);
}
```

Comment: Which line causes error?

Comment: What is code of `generateRequestID()`?

Comment: Seems that your error comes from `makeCustom_Click()` method. Provide inner exception for more details and which line throwing error, since exception related with `CompilerServices.Symbols.Container` is very common issue.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto after debugging exception coming in this line "string FileName = Path.GetFileName(artworkContainer.PostedFile.FileName);"

Comment: @Hemal generateRquestID is working properly. This method is made to generate random alphanumeric value. There is no problem in that

Comment: Has `artworkContainer.PostedFile.FileName` contains empty or null string? `GetFileName` returns null if the `FileName` property supplied is null, hence it may propagate to throw `NullReferenceException`. I want to know how you get the filename and attach it then.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto File Name is coming fine as attached name of file. Path goes Nothing.

Comment: I see that `artworkContainer` is a file upload control on web form, hence you may check with `Server.MapPath(artworkContainer.PostedFile.FileName)` to see absolute path of attached file. And examine in case you have file upload control wrapped inside update panel, since upload control requires `PostBackTrigger` (also `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) on it.